# algorithm/formula for finding corresponding control point indexes of a closed path of bezier curves

Tags: algorithms, bezier-curve

[image]

From the image above, I have 4 bezier curves that form a closed path, numbered from 0 to 11 (number of points - 1). 
Say the main corners $(0, 3, 6, 9)$ are Anchor Points and the in-between points $(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11)$ are Control Points, how can I find

i). A formula to arrive at an individual bezier curve’s corresponding control point from one control point?

Example, n = 8 => 7 and n = 7=> 8, n = 1 => 2 and n = 2 => 1 and so on

ii). A formula to find the two corresponding anchor points for an individual bezier curve’s control point?

Example n = 11 => 9 and 0, also n = 5 => 3 and 6, where n is index of a control or anchor point on the bezier curves path.

Please note that these formula’s should work in general for any *r* number of bezier curves that form a closed path.